# SQL Count people who have all 4 grandparents

Tags: sql, oracle, select

So I have these following tables:

1) ADDRESS `PERSON_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | STREET | HOUSE | ROOM | ZIPCODE | CITY`

2) IDENTIFIER `NR | PERSON_ID | ISSUE_DATE | VALID_UNTIL`

3) MARRIAGE `WIFE_ID | HUSBAND_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE`

4) PERSON `ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | BIRTHDATE | MOTHER_ID | FATHER_ID`

And my task is to calculate the number of people who have all 4 grandparents recorded in the database.
So if I got it right, I have to find all the people in the table where both `MOTHER_ID` and `FATHER_ID` are not null, whose `MOTHER_ID` and `FATHER_ID` columns are also not null.

What I have for now is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PERSON
WHERE MOTHER_ID IS NOT NULL AND FATHER_ID IS NOT NULL
```

which returns the number of people who have both parents recorded in the database and I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Where is the record for grandparents? Do you have any other table or columns that has records of grandparents?

Comment: I've updated the post with rest of the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd join the table on itself twice, once for the father and once for the mother, and then check their parents:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   person p
JOIN   person f ON p.father_id = f.id AND f.father_id IS NOT NULL AND f.mother_id IS NOT NULL
JOIN   person m ON p.mother_id = m.id AND m.father_id IS NOT NULL AND m.mother_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join two instance of Person table together and then select rows with four mother|father_1|2 is not null.
the sql is something like this.

```
SELECT p1.father_id AS father_id_1, p2.father_id AS father_id_2,p1.mother_id AS mother_id_1,p2.mother_id AS mother_id_2, 
FROM Person p1
JOIN Person p2 ON p1.FATHER_ID = p2.ID and p1.MOTHER_ID = p2.ID
```